# Opencart - changing the default address for products

Tags: url, opencart

I've been trying to find an answer to this all day but no luck so far. Basically what I need is to change the default route for the products like so:

site.com/product1 -> site.com/goods/product1
site.com/product2 -> site.com/goods/product2

I expected this to be an often asked question but I wasn't able to find the solution so far.

Comment: Basically you want add goods before product url share your oc version and you can change directly in your code?

Comment: Yes, I want to add /goods/ before the product. Sorry, I don't understand the rest of what you wrote, can you rephrase that?

Comment: Which Version of opencart you are using , 2.x or 3.x. 
Can you change your code of opencart or you want make module?

Comment: It's 2.3 and I'd like to change code instead of using a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is the workaround I was able to write that somehow works. It goes into the public function index() of the seo_pro.php file. Basically I copied part the original routing which is specifically used to work with products and rewrote it to use /goods/ in the url.

```
if (explode("/",$this->request->get['_route_'])[0]=='goods') {      
      
    $route_ = $this->request->get['_route_'];
    unset($this->request->get['_route_']);
    $parts = explode('/', trim(utf8_strtolower($route_), '/'));
    
    list($last_part) = explode('.', array_pop($parts));
    array_push($parts, $last_part);
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($parts as $keyword) {
        if (isset($this->cache_data['keywords'][$keyword])) {
            $rows[] = array('keyword' => $keyword, 'query' => $this->cache_data['keywords'][$keyword]);
        }
    }    
    $queries = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $queries[utf8_strtolower($row['keyword'])] = $row['query'];                         
    }
    reset($parts);
    if (count($parts) > 2) {
        return new Action($this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found');
    }
    $url = explode('=', $queries[$parts[1]]);
    $this->request->get[$url[0]] = $url[1];
        
    if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $path = $this->getPathByProduct($this->request->get['product_id']);
            if ($path) $this->request->get['path'] = $path;
        }
    }
    return new Action($this->request->get['route']);                        
}
```

At the moment is just checks what goes after /goods/ and does the usual thing as if there was no /goods/ in it. There should be several additional checks added to make this more secure but it's out of the scope of this question.

**Update 1:**
I have also added a redirect from the default product link to this one in the same seo_pro.php file:

```
$newUrl = '/goods/' . $this->request->request['_route_'];
header("Location:" . $newUrl,TRUE,301);
```

All what's left now is to find where Opencart stores default links so that if would generate the /goods/ in the url by default.

**Update 2:**
Okay, found where Opencart generates links. It's in the /catalog/controllers/ folder. Just had to find the chunk of code responsible for product/product and rewrite the url before it starts working with it, kinda like this:

```
$newUrl = explode('/', rtrim($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']), '/'));
array_splice($newUrl, 3, 0, 'goods');
$newUrl = implode('/', $newUrl) .'/';
```

And then I feed it to the $data['products'][] array:

```
'href' => $newUrl
```

I think this concludes my efforts here, will mark this as answered.